# Looking for a web-service that returns a XML (1MB or bigger) to test a solution for performance problems

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, xmlhttprequest

I would like to test something and therefore i need to access or call a web-service with http post. That service, no matter what kind of information, should just send back a big xml file. 1-10 MB. I would like to parse the response stream.

I just need the URL and parameters, nothing more.It can be from google, yahoo, amazon, some strange chinacompany, all you got!! A web-service that returns a xml.

edit: Nobody uses some web service from amazon or yahoo?

Answer (score 0):

XML of that huge sizes are rare to be served by other sites. Probably you can build your own local webserver that can deliver such a large XML files... alternatively you can try to see if you can get some rssfeed like http://feeds.feedburner.com/Makeuseof?format=xml

I don't think that will in the orders you wanted it, but it is sure to be big.